# point to partial in expess-generator site

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I generated a express website using express-generator and i need to reference a partial hbs file that is inside a subfolder within the views folder.

my folder Structure is like this

[image]

From within my main layout file (layout.hbs) i am referencing the head and nav_bar files which i get an error that the head file cant be found

[image]

Error is

```
C:\MovementForNewNigeria\app\views\index.hbs: The partial head could not be found

Error: C:\MovementForNewNigeria\app\views\index.hbs: The partial head could not be found
at Object.invokePartial (C:\MovementForNewNigeria\app\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\runtime.js:266:11)
at Object.invokePartialWrapper [as invokePartial] (C:\MovementForNewNigeria\app\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\runtime.js:68:39)
at Object.eval (eval at createFunctionContext (C:\MovementForNewNigeria\app\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\javascript-compiler.js:254:23), <anonymous>:6:28)
at main (C:\MovementForNewNigeria\app\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\runtime.js:173:32)
at ret (C:\MovementForNewNigeria\app\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\runtime.js:176:12)
at ret (C:\MovementForNewNigeria\app\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\compiler.js:525:21)
at C:\MovementForNewNigeria\app\node_modules\hbs\lib\hbs.js:87:17
at C:\MovementForNewNigeria\app\node_modules\hbs\lib\hbs.js:69:11
at done (C:\MovementForNewNigeria\app\node_modules\hbs\lib\async.js:74:20)
at C:\MovementForNewNigeria\app\node_modules\hbs\lib\hbs.js:64:20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to register the partial or more efficiently register all partials

with

```
var hbs = require('hbs');
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
```

https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs

Thanks to turmuka for helping with the hbs import.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this code right here. It is going to register the path you have specified.

```
app.engine('hbs', hbs({
    extname: 'hbs', 
    defaultLayout: 'base', 
    layoutDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts', // for layouts
    partialsDir  : [
        //  path to your partials
        __dirname + '/views/partials',
    ]
}));
```

Comment: let me know what it returns

Comment: its saying hbs is not defined...how do i import that

Comment: try creating a `layouts` directory and move your files there,

Comment: using the express generator https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Comment: on what line does it say `hbs` undefined? in which file? can you update it to the question please

Comment: its when i added app.engine('hbs', hbs({
    extname: 'hbs', 
    defaultLayout: 'base', 
    layoutDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts', // for layouts
    partialsDir  : [
        //  path to your partials
        __dirname + '/views/partials',
    ]
}));  to my app.js

Comment: @JoshuaMajebi thank you. You made my day, I've learned something new

Comment: `hbs()` can execute if you use `express-hbs` module, but express-generator use `hbs` module for express template engine

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the partial with the "registerPartials" function, like explained in this [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbs), BUT you have to do it like this:

```
var hbs = require('hbs');
var path = require('path');
hbs.registerPartials(path.join(__dirname + '/views/partials'));
```

If you skip the "path.join" part, you can get errors on Windows for example, because the path would then be "C:\some-dev-folder\express-app/views/partials" instead of "C:\some-dev-folder\express-app\views\partials"